# Non-blocking pthread stop - or why does std::atomic_flag slow down my code

Tags: c++, performance, pthreads, atomic

I implemented a little multithreaded application which does the following:

**MainThread**

> A main thread starts a timer using `setitimer` and starts up to 8
>   threads. The timer from the main thread is used to read repeatedly from > a file (every 0.25s). When the timer is called 20 times (after ~5s), I 
>   want to stop the threads and get the amount of computations done 
>   by every thread.

MainThread.h

```
class MainThread {
  private:
    int counter;
    ThreadManager tm;
    bool registerTimer(double seconds);
    void startTimerWithInterval(double interval);
    void read() {
      /**
       *  If counter >= 20, call stopWorker on all threads
       */
      tm.stopWorkers();
    }
  public:
    MainThread():counter(0){}
}
```

**WorkerThreads**

> Perform some expensive computations whithin an infinity loop.
>   After a certain amount of computations, the thread has to store the
>   number of computations it performed. This value (amount of computations) 
>   has to be quite accurate, so i think I have to stop the threads (quite) 
>   immediatly.

ThreadClass.h

```
class WorkerThread { 
  private:
    /**
     * ...
     */
    std::atomic_flag keep_Running = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

    static void* run(void* args) {
      ((WorkerThread*)args)->process();
      pthread_exit(nullptr);
      return nullptr;
    }

  public:
    /**
     * ...
     */
    bool startWorker() {
      keep_Running.test_and_set();
      bool result = (pthread_create(&thread, pthread_attr, run, this) == 0);
      if(!result) {
        keep_Running.clear();
      }
      return result;
    }
    void stopWorker() {
      keep_Running.clear();
    }
    bool keepRunning() {
      return keep_Running.test_and_set();
    }
    virtual void process() = 0;
};
```

ComputationThread.h

```
class ComputationThread : public WorkerThread {
  public:
    virtual void process() override {
      /**
       *  Perform computations with ~400MB data
       *  check every 16B, whether keepRunning still true
       */
      bool keep_running = true;
      while(keep_running) {
        /**
         * Process 4B
         */
        keep_running = keepRunning();
      }
    }
};
```

If I use some kind of flag, to track the running state of a thread, i have to make this flag threadsafe, don't I? I tried a `std::atomic_flag` because it should be lock-free and has atomic operations, but this results in a **dramatically drop** of performance. My question is, does the `std::atomic_flag` causes the performance drop or is this just because I perform the check way too often? Does anyone knows a better way?

Before you ask, I HAVE to use `pthread` instead of `std::thread` to assign a thread to a specified core within the thread creation (using `pthread_attrib_t`).

Comment: Why do you need to assign a thread to a specific core?

Comment: Because there are different cores

Comment: OS does that by itself, you only make things worse

Comment: ........ Thanks for the answer.

Comment: you are welcome. 99% of people who are doing thread to core affinity never measured if there is a real improvement in performance. They do it because it makes them fill smart.

Comment: :D Well trust me. I tested it. And I don't do this for fun or because I think I am super smart. I just have different cores with different frequencies and I have to determine, on which core a thread runs......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134121/discussion-between-hymir-and-slava).

Comment: sorry, cannot do chat, it is blocked by my emp

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `std::atomic_flag`.

It is meant as a low level `atomic` primitive and therefore has a very limited interface.
Its main limitation is that you can only test its value by setting it to true in a single `atomic` call named `test_and_set()`
This is a Read-Modify-Write operation (RMW) which performs expensive synchronization between all cores.
Since you are calling this on every loop iteration, it slows down significantly.

Use a regular `atomic<bool>` and set it once you are finished.
This way, inside the loop you only have to read it, which is an `atomic` load and that translates to a regular `mov` operation.
Setting a specific memory order will have no impact on performance (at least on X86).

Comment: That sounds terrific! Thank you for clarifying. I think a even better approach is, to perform a threadsafe copy of the current amount value within the stopWorker method. So we only have to check the bool once per loop and we still get the correct result!

Comment: @Hymir I would be interested to get some feedback on the overall performance impact when `atomic_flag` is no longer used.

Comment: Tests are running. I will get the data at monday!

Answer (score 0):

[`std::atomic_flag::test_and_set()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test_and_set) includes a default argument of [`std::memory_order`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) `order = memory_order_seq_cst`

> Atomic operations tagged `memory_order_seq_cst` not only order memory the same way as release/acquire ordering (everything that happened-before a store in one thread becomes a visible side effect in the thread that did a load), but also establish a single total modification order of all atomic operations that are so tagged.
>
> ...
>
> Total sequential ordering requires a full memory fence CPU instruction on all multi-core systems. **This may become a performance bottleneck since it forces the affected memory accesses to propagate to every core.**

This flag for the `memory_order` is going to cause each thread to perform its memory operations for `test_and_set` in order, loading and saving to memory sequentially, which is going to be slower as each thread is going to spend time waiting on the other threads to perform their memory operations.

Comment: Every worker thread holds its own std::atomic_flag. I just want to ensure, that the workerthread doesn't read a undefined state because a write from the main thread. Would it be a better approach to use a mutex, or an other std::memory_order?

Comment: Well I don't know, what happens if one thread reads while another writes a bool. Fun fact: If I just use a bool, the program doesn't terminate. I just read: std::atomic_flag is lock free and atomic and I thought: "Well, that sounds awesome".

Comment: @Hymir Then just increase interval you are checking that flag and overhead would't matter

Comment: @Ics memory order `seq_cst` will not slow it down, probably generates the exact same code